# Unassign browse button on the flow.js HTML5 upload component

Tags: javascript, flow-js

With the [flow.js](https://github.com/flowjs/flow.js) component we can assign a browse button like this:

```
flow.assignBrowse(document.getElementById('browseButton'));
```

We can assign a drop area like this:

```
flow.assignDrop(document.getElementById('dropTarget'));
```

We can also unassign a drop area like this:

```
flow.unAssignDrop(document.getElementById('dropTarget'));
```

**My first question is how to unassign a browse button ?**

**My second question is how to know (natively) if a browse button is already defined ?**

I can't see any info on that in the documentation.

Thanks.

Comment: If I take your two questions literally I would answer : with `flow.js` or wihtout it browse button is an `<input>` tag, then remove it or searching for it is no magic using the DOM methods or jQuery's. But I think that your question has more depth that I can't figure out unless you help me by adding more clarifications to what are you really asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How to unassign browse?**

There is no built-in way, but you just need to reverse what `assignBrowse` is doing, which basically adds an input similar to the following to the element you select:

```
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; width: 1px; height: 1px;">
```

To revert that, you could assign an ID to that input, which you can basically do by providing to `assignBrowse` (which  takes the following params: `domNodes`, `isDirectory`, `singleFile`, `attributes`) an `[{"id":"myId"}]` array in place of the `attributes` param so that you can target it later and destroy that element:

```
function myUnassign(){
    document.getElementById("myId").remove()
}
```

**How to know (natively) if a browse button is already defined ?**

By checking if the `input` element exists. Similar approach to the one above, check if an element with a previously assigned ID exists already.